# Creating Forms using Modals in angular2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I was trying a modal with a form to take certain inputs from the user. I had a button to open the modal but on clicking the button, the project is directly routed to the home page without opening the modal(restarting the project).
Here's the Modal HTML code :

```html
   <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm">Add new Records</button>
            </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body mx-3">
      <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
        <input type="text" id="name" >
        <label for="defaultForm-name">Patient Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="md-form mb-4">
        <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
        <input type="text" id="disease" >
        <label  for="defaultForm-disease">Diseases</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the complete HTML Code :

```html
<header>

    <div class="sidebar-fixed position-fixed">

        <a class="logo-wrapper waves-effect">
            <img src="../../../../assets/img/logo.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="">  
        </a>

        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">

            <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action waves-effect">
                <mdb-icon fas icon="chart-pie" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>Dashboard</a>
            <a routerLink="profile" routerLinkActive="active" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action waves-effect">
                <mdb-icon fas icon="user" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>Profile</a>
        </div>

        <br><br><br>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm">Add new Records</button>
            </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body mx-3">
      <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
        <input type="text" id="name" >
        <label for="defaultForm-name">Patient Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="md-form mb-4">
        <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
        <input type="text" id="disease" >
        <label  for="defaultForm-disease">Diseases</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


        <br><br>
        <p>Year Wise Medical Records</p>

        <div class="list-group "  *ngFor="let year of years | async">
              
            <a routerLink="records"  routerLinkActive="active" >
                <mdb-icon fas icon="table" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>{{year.key}}</a>
                
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->

    <!--Navbar-->
    <mdb-navbar [containerInside]="false" SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light white">

        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <logo class="ml-3">
            <a class="logo-wrapper waves-effect">
                    <img src="../../../../assets/img/male_avatar.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="border-radius: 50%"> 
            </a>
        </logo>

        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <links style="padding-left: 5%">

            <!-- Links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <h5> Akhilesh </h5>
                    <h5> Male </h5>
                    <h5> 21 years </h5>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Links -->

            <!-- Search form -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <button (click) = "pdfGen()"> Download PDF </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </links>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        
    </mdb-navbar>
    <!--/.Navbar-->

</header>
<!--Main Navigation-->
```

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Maybe try removing the href?

Comment: I tried removing the href, but the button doesn't work. Is there any way possible? @MikeOne

Comment: You mean then the button doesn’t open the modal?

Comment: yes
I changed it to this :
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm">Launch
  Modal Login Form</button>

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a  tag with an empty herf wich reference to your app start point you have to remove href artt

Comment: I tried removing the href, but the button doesn't work. Is there any way possible?

Comment: I think that is an issue of implementing the modal itself can you let me know which modal you use ?!

Comment: I'm using bootstrap modal

Comment: try to use a button instead of anchor

Comment: yes I changed it to this : <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm">Launch Modal Login Form</button>  

But it still didn't work....if I'm going with href...what should I add in href instead of having it empty?

Comment: Href should contian an url or an id reference to scroll your page up and down in the same bage.

Comment: Double check your modal configurations and installation or use ng-bootstrap modal instade it easier to use and more compatible with angualr.